# what are the references that support string operation in vba

Tags: vba

```
Dim msg_Id As String
msg_Id = .Cells(rcount, 3).Value
msg_Id = Mid(msg_Id, 0, 3)
```

It throws error like invalid procedue call or argument

As I am new to Vb.net I don't know hoe to rectify this error, do I need to include any reference to support this operation

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first thing you should do is set [option strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) **On**.

Comment: even though i use set there is no change its throwing "Object required " error at line Set msg_Id = Mid(msg_Id, 0, 3)

Comment: If you've truly done as advised, then you've changed your code. Please update your question.

Comment: could you please tell me how to on the option strict

Comment: @surya4969 If you look closely at the first comment, you will see it has a hyperlink to the instructions for Option Strict.

Comment: sorry for disturbing you please bare me for some time when i use "Optin Strict On" in my code It says "Expected: Base or Compare or Explicit or Private"

Comment: @surya4969 Double click `My Project` in the `Solution` pane and click the `Compile` tab. Look at this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gvfOf.png

Comment: I googled, somewhere i came to know that there is no option like option strict in VBA. Even I searched ni n VBA I didn't found any option like that. :(

Comment: @surya4969 `VBA` is **not** the same as `vb.net`.

Comment: Then how to compile my code in VBA with out ERROR

Comment: start by using the correct tags on your question; as is you are asking for .NET answers which you have gotten.

Comment: sorry basically i'm new to VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx

It is not about a reference. This error rise when:

> Start <= 0 or Length < 0.

You should change your code having in mind that first char is in position 1, not 0

```
Dim msg_Id As String
msg_Id = .Cells(rcount, 3).Value
msg_Id = Mid(msg_Id, 1, 3)
```

Comment: You will get an error with .Cells(rcount, 3).Value as well unless it is contained in a "With" block.

Comment: Of course. I assumed OP pasted just a small piece of code where the error was thrown.

Comment: Only reason I didn't assume was that was the Dim statement at the top.  I'm sure your right, and he just omitted the "With" statement.